# Implementation of quick select in python. function is unstable and returns different values

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort, quickselect

I tried to implement quick select to find the m'th smallest number in the list. When I run the program it returns the correct values sometime and incorrect values other times on the same array. What am I doing wrong her is the code

```
def select_mth_smallest(A, m):
    pivot = np.random.choice(A)
    # split into 3 partitions
    A1 = [] 
    A2 = []
    A3 = []
    for item in A:
        if item < pivot:
            A1.append(item)
        if item > pivot:
            A3.append(item)
        else:
            A2.append(item)
    #find where m'th largest element is and recurse accordingly
    if len(A1) >= m:
        return select_mth_smallest(A1, m)
    elif (len(A1) + len(A2)) >= m:
        return pivot
    else:
        return select_mth_smallest(A3,m - (len(A1)+len(A2)))
```

Here is an input where the algorithm fails.

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]

select_mth_smallest(A,5)
```

When I repeatedly execute this above statement I get, 5(correct) and 4(incorrect) alternatingly.

One thing that particularly baffles me (I am new to python) is that why I get different return values for the function when repeated with the same input. Looks rather sporadic.. BTW I am using Jupyter

Comment: Look at your `if`s and `elif`s. One of those is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I checked it seems to be correct. Can you be more specific. Thanks

Comment: Is it the mth largest or smallest? Your title, function name, and comment seem to disagree. ~~Also what happens if pivot happens to be the smallest item in the current `A`? Then `A1` will be empty, as nothing is smaller than the pivot, and you'll be calling `select_mth_smallest([], m)`, in which case [`numpy.random.choice` will raise a `ValueError`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html).~~ There are a few of edge cases that you need to account for. What if the pivot is the mth smallest/largest element? Edit: misread the conditionals

Comment: but this will not be executed since it is under the if clause and 0 is always less than a positive integer.

Comment: @Prag1 yes, for some reason strikethrough is not parsed in comments

Comment: @user2357112 Do you agree with me? Is there a bug in my code. The if elif statements appear to be correct, please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @KevinOrr what I mean by m'th smallest element is : when you sort it in ascending order it is the m'th element. Also if pivot is the m'th smallest element then I don't see a problem, the function will return after just one recursion.

Comment: [Please provide an input where the algorithm fails.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Prag1 okay, but `A2` is going to contain all elements <= `pivot`. Often, you'll be returning `pivot` even if it isn't the mth *smallest* element.

Comment: @chepner thanks! I have edited the question including the input..

Comment: @KevinOrr all elements in A2 are equal to the pivot and according to the conditionals' logic I don't think I will be returning pivot incorrectly

Comment: @Prag1 no, the elements in A2 are those that are *not greater than* the pivot. Using a debugger or adding a couple of print statements would make this evident. As user2357112 said, check your `if` statements, especially `if item > pivot`. When will the else clause be called?

Comment: @Prag1 as for why you get different results on each invocation, that is because your function is non-deterministic. What do you think the source of randomness is?

Comment: Got it ! thanks. I should have written an elif item > pivot. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding some items to multiple partitions.

```
    if item < pivot:
        A1.append(item)
    if item > pivot:
        A3.append(item)
    else:
        A2.append(item)
```

`A1` is the set of items less than the pivot. `A3` is the set of items greater than the pivot. `A2`, however, is the set of items *less than or equal* to the pivot, because the 2nd `if` statement executes for *all* items, and one or the other branch will execute.

You want one, single `if` statement with an `elif` and `else` clause here.

```
    if item < pivot:
        A1.append(item)
    elif item > pivot:
        A3.append(item)
    else:
        A2.append(item)
```